# How to properly desructure a derived class object when derived class pointer is assigned to base class pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers, destructor, radix, derived

Is it possible to delete derived class object in proper way when derived class pointer was assigned to base class pointer? Lets consider following situation:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <stddef.h>


class Signal{
    public:
    Signal (int val) : x(val){};
    int x;
    
    virtual ~Signal(){
        std::cout<<"base class destructor"<<std::endl;
    }

};


class Timer : public Signal{
    public:
    Timer (int val) : Signal(val), y(val+1){};
    double y;  
    virtual ~Timer(){
        std::cout<<"derived class destructor"<<std::endl;
    };
};


int main()
{
    std::cout<<"start"<<std::endl;
    Timer* t = new Timer(9);
    Signal* s = t;
    
    delete s;
    std::cout<<t->x <<std::endl;
    std::cout<<t->y <<std::endl;
    s = NULL;


if (t != NULL){
    delete t;
}
    std::cout<<"end"<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This will print:

> start
> derived class destructor
> base class destructor
> -340049904
> 10
>
> ...Program finished with exit code 0
> Press ENTER to exit console.

I just wonder if it  is possible.  Of course i try to avoid following asigment "Signal* s = t;" and it works.

I expected, that "end" will be printed but it is not. It seems like the program stops on "delete t". The same behavior I am observing with and without "t != NULL" check.

Comment: `delete s;` is ok as - _"...or a pointer to a base subobject of a non-array object created by a new-expression. ..."_  [delete](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/delete).  However the following 2 lines after the delete are UB as the object has been deleted. `delete t;` is also UB as the object has been deleted.

Comment: `std::cout<<t->x <<std::endl;
    std::cout<<t->y <<std::endl;` is _undefined behavior_.

Comment: On a side note, passing a null pointer to `delete` is fine, so there is no need to check.

Comment: You're wondering if *what* is possible? `delete s;` destroys the object, and trying to access it after that point is undefined. Also, `t != NULL` is always true since you never assign `t` a new value. (Are you assuming that you can determine whether an object exists by comparing with the null pointer?)

Comment: `s` and `t` point to the same object. Once you `delete s;` you deleted the pointed object, meaning you deleted the object `t` was also pointing to. `t` now has an invalid pointer value and trying to dereference it is an error, it doesn't point to anything in particular. `Signal s = t;` doesn't copy the object, it just makes another pointer that points to the same thing.

Comment: Some revision of the basic concept of pointers is needed. Copying a pointer copies the pointer, not the object being pointed to.

Comment: Consider: I point at an apple and say "there's an apple!". Then somebody else points at the same apple and says "there's a fruit!" and immediately throws the fruit in the garbage. I haven't moved a finger. Am I still pointing at an apple? Can I eat it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Timer* t = new Timer(9);
Signal* s = t;

delete s;
std::cout<<t->x <<std::endl;
```

You cannot access `t`, with `cout << t->x` after `delete s;`. This deletion destroyed both `t` and `s`, which are actually the same object.

Just wait to be done with printing (or anything else) before deleting.